# The cron script fails when executed

Tags: magento-1.7, cron

When cron on the server kicks off to start the magento cron, an exception is thrown in var/reports with the error:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:31:"Invalid cron expression: always";i:1;s:1245:"#0 /home/magento/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Schedule.php(68): Mage::exception('Mage_Cron', 'Invalid cron ex...') 
#1 /home/magento/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(214): Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule->setCronExpr('always') 
#2 /home/magento/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(168): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_generateJobs(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Array) 
#3 /home/magento/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(128): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->generate() 
#4 /home/magento/magento/app/code/local/Xtento/OrderExport/Model/Observer/Cron/Config.php(22): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer)) 
#5 /home/magento/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Xtento_OrderExport_Model_Observer_Cron_Config->addCronjobsToConfig(Object(Varien_Event_Observer)) 
#6 /home/magento/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1311): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Xtento_OrderExport_Model_Observer_Cron_Config), 'addCronjobsToCo...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer)) 
#7 /home/magento/magento/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array) 
#8 /home/magento/magento/cron.php(73): Mage::dispatchEvent('default') 
#9 {main}";s:11:"script_name";s:31:"/home/magento/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Answer (score 1):

The cron expression `always` is not valid.
Use `* * * * *` instead.
[See a detailed explanation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm) on how the cron expressions should look.

Comment: Thanks for the solution...every where in my code i used  * * * * * for cron_expr. but in Core/Enterprise/Index/etc/config.xml it is given "always" for cron_expr.  if i change it to * * * * * it is working fine. But we cant override config.xml file in our local... can u plz provide a better solution... or the issue with this "always" in config.xml